# Inequality on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disc and let $g\in H(\mathbb{D})$ with $\operatorname{Re}(g(z))>0, \, \forall z\in \mathbb{D}$.
Prove \begin{align}\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}\leq \operatorname{Re}(g(z))\leq \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|} \end{align}
for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$.
I think, Schwarz's Lemma will be useful for this one, but I can't find a proper transformation, so I can use it ($g(0)=1$). Any suggestions?

Comment: There must be something wrong in the assumptions on $g$. For $z=0$ you would get $\operatorname{Re}(g(0)) = 1$, which is not possible for $g: \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: @MartinR it‘s no corrected.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes, thank you. But how is it secured, that the image of the unit disc is in the unit disc, to use schwarz‘s proposition?